# Singleton use within objects or passed as reference

Tags: oop, object

I program in PHP but this is a general Object orientation question.

What do we feel about calling singleton classes from within an object vs calling one outside and passing the variable in?

Option one:

```
$instance = Singleton::getInstance();

$obj = new ClassName();
$obj->setSingleton($instance);
```

Option two:

```
class ClassName
{
     public function __construct(){
         $instance = Singleton::getInstance();
         $instance->doSomething();
     }
}
```

Is this just a "per-use" decision (i.e. singleton implementing interface, etc) or are there rules?

I can see passing objects VS singletons but one about singleton instances vs calling? Think typical code with lots of classes and many uses for the singleton instance... Are there any rules for this?

Comment: I'm generally not a fan of Singletons at all, but if you get the instane inside the object, then that object becomes tightly coupled with the singleton. And if that happens everywhere in the code, then the problem worsens. But it might be just as bad passing the instance into every object that needs it!.

Comment: @chatton it seems either method has a downside but singleton's are a very common design pattern. you can see why I am curious in this case

Comment: Yeah definitely, I think @AlexG made a good point in his answer in regards to the code being less obvious to anybody reading it. If I was to choose one, I would go for passing the reference rather than calling getInstance() inside the methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either is fine, but when others will look at your code it might be less obvious they're dealing with a singleton in your option #1, especially if the code grows big. IMHO it's perfectly valid to keep a reference of your singleton in the body of a function when you need to call it a few times in a row, but I wouldn't keep it as member variable.

Keeping a member variable also implies your objects will be bigger for no apparent reason.